# How do you create a "constant dataframe" in pandas for the sake of adding / subtracting / comparing other dataframes to a constant value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, constants

I'm working with `pybacktest`, trying to create my own BackTester that will support  not only "buy" / "sell" but also "stay" (the middle ground - do nothing).

```
ohlc = pybacktest.load_from_yahoo('AAPL', start=2000)   # Load a pandas dataframe
ohlc.tail()

ms = ohlc.C.rolling(short_ma).mean()
ml = ohlc.C.rolling(long_ma).mean()

eps = 0.001

up = (ms > ml + eps) & (ms.shift() < ml.shift())      # ma cross up
stay = (ml - eps <= ms <= ml + eps)
down = (ms < ml - eps) & (ms.shift() > ml.shift())    # ma cross down
```

The last part of the code is what I want to do.  The code as it exists in the pybacktest tutorial is:

```
buy = cover = (ms > ml) & (ms.shift() < ml.shift())  # ma cross up
sell = short = (ms < ml) & (ms.shift() > ml.shift())  # ma cross down
```

And I'm changing buy / sell to up / down to more closely model the instrument I'm trading.  And there is no cover / short for this instrument.  So I've created my own class and copied the `Backtest` class code into it, and have started editing.  But this has to do with pandas dataframes.

The error I'm getting is related to the fact that I just used a python floating point and tried adding / subtracting it from a dataframe:

[image: WingWare IDE screenshot]

It would have been nice if you could simply do that (I would have coded pandas that way), but you can't.  So my question is simple and probably easy to answer.  Pandas dataframes usually hold complex-looking data.  I'm desiring the opposite of that... all I want is a constant value for every timestamped row in `ohlc`!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was about not handling the series a <= b <= c unambiguously.

Simplly convert it to:

```
stay = (ml - eps <= ms) & (ms <= ml + eps)
```

Using & logic.  So pandas *does* handle +/-/* with constants and casting!  Amazing!